# How to transform a line to circle curve.

Tags: geometry, circles, transformation

I am facing a problem of the transformation of a line to a circle curve as shown in the attached figure.

[image]

The line segment $A1Z1$ which has many points$(A1(x_A,y_A), B1(x_B,y_B),...P1(x_P,y_P),...)$ is needed to transform to a circle curve $A2Z2 (\theta,R$).

So far I do not know how to get the coordinate of the corresponding points of the circle curve.

Hope for your help and thank you very much.
Dave.

Comment: Are you familiar with parametrizations? Circles are parametrized as $(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the line connecting the origin and the point and the $y$-axis. You would use this fact to get the transformation.

Comment: For each point on the line you could calculate the intersection with arc (circle) if you know that circle equation.

Answer (score 1):

@ndhanson3, @Moti, Thank you very much for your comments. Parametrization is really a key word.
Let me answer myself.

The parametrization of a line segment is written as:
$$\begin{cases}
x = (x_Z-x_A)t + x_A, \quad where \; t\in[0,1]\\
y = (y_Z-y_A)t + y_A 
\end{cases}$$
so
$$ t = \frac{x-x_A}{x_Z-x_A} , \quad where \; t\in[0,1]$$
while the parametrization of an arc is written as
$$\begin{cases}
\hat{x} = Rsin(\hat{t}), \quad where \; \hat{t} \in [0,\theta]\\
\hat{y} = Rcos(\hat{t})
\end{cases}$$
It is a transformation from $t\in[0,1]$ to $\hat{t}\in[0,\theta]$, so $\hat{t}$ is computed
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{t} &= (\theta-0)\bigg(\frac{t-0}{1-0}\bigg) + 0 \\
        &= \theta t \\
        &= \theta \bigg(\frac{x-x_A}{x_Z-x_A}\bigg)
\end{aligned}$$
Subtitution into the arc equation, the transformation of the arc has the parametric equation
$$\begin{cases}
\hat{x} = Rsin\Big(\theta \big(\frac{x-x_A}{x_Z-x_A}\big) \Big), \\
\hat{y} = Rcos\Big(\theta \big(\frac{x-x_A}{x_Z-x_A}\big) \Big)
\end{cases}$$

Best,-Dave.